# Biztalk- flat file schema definitions

Tags: schema, biztalk

I have defined a flat file schema which works fine. However, I got now a new requirement for this schema: It has to support future potential additional fields in the end of the records.

The solution I used is quit "ugly". I added an additional filler at the end of the record and configured it as "minOccurs = 0" and set Allow early termination of optional fileds to true.

This works but I don't like it.

It seems to me that there must be a property for ignoring any additional fields after the last one, so I won't need  this filler field.

Does anyone familiar with such option/ property?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, what you've done is the correct way to handle this situation.  Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

The Flat File Parser requires all possible content be defined in the schema so it doesn't ever have to 'guess' what's next.

Answer (score 1):

When a flat file changes, the schema must change as well. That is part of the job for a BizTalk developer.

You can't anticipate changes to the flat file inside your schema. With the filler field you have now, what are you going to do if 2 extra fields appear and have to be used? How will you get the data in, say, a mapping?

This is the way the flat file parser works, everything has to be well defined and if the specs change you must update your schemas. There is no magic here to make it all completely dynamic. Unless if you were to write a custom flat file disassembler from scratch that supports it, but good luck with that.